# GUI Development for a ROBOT Compatible with ROS and WINDOWS

Tags: windows, user-interface, ros, platform

for a project i have been assigned, I have been given 2 robots...one has ROS and the other basically uses Windows. So my task is to develop  one Graphic User Interface that can be used for both robots.

From the GUI , a user should be able to.
- Connect to the Robot
- Move and control the robot.
- Change speed...etc

I will like to ask for advice as i am about to start this project.
How can i go about this? and which has better support for my requirements?

From my research i have read people recommend QT...for cross platform developmens. Are there any other alternatives? any book recommendations?

The goal will be to have a GUI that is compatible for both systems. Any Recommendations or help is welcomed.

Comment: I suggest using python instead of C++ and QT framework.

Comment: If you want to bring up the ROS in the windows platform, you can use the [ROS-Docker_link1](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker), [ROS_Docker_link2](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/ros/#volumes)

Comment: Hi Benyamin sounds like a good advice! i will try using python then. i will also check the possibility of the Docker. My start point will be how to establish a connection between the Robot having ROS and the my windows Laptop....

Answer (score 0):

First you setup ROS On windows Using WSL (or any other ways to do it WSL is most stable).

after that you need achieve everything you want the GUI does on robot using ROS terminal.

after that your write the GUI. You can Choose any framework You want(You need C++ or Python for compatibility issues with ROS) but QT Framework is most used in multi platform Application and has a lot of support.

the compatibility with non-ROS is what You should Implement in your Application Like Choosing or something Like that.

Answer (score 0):

[PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org) is a framework built on top of tkinter that runs on the Pi.  There are some example programs written to do robot remote control.  There are GUI buttons designed specifically for "realtime" control of hardware that will provide immediate and constant feedback when a button is held.

It runs on Python 2.7 and 3 (recommend 3).

There is a Recipe in the Cookbook that matches your problem located [here](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/cookbook/#realtime-buttons-good-for-raspberry-pi).

If you use PySimpleGUI in your project, post in the Issues area on GitHub if you have any questions and you'll get support.

Comment: HI thanks, i will check it out and i will let you know.

Comment: Sure thing... I just made a bunch of changes to Realtime buttons, enabling them to work with timeouts so that you can set a specific polling frequency.  Previously you had to add sleeps if you wanted to poll at a particular interval.  Now you can use the GUI to do the timing for you by adding a timeout to the read.  I've updated the Demo programs and the Cookbook to include these new design patterns.  I've seen a few other robotic projects pop up on GitHub that's using PSG.